# What software to modify and create TCP/IP packets?

Tags: windows, networking, network-monitor

I am learning about network packets and I was wondering how I could intercept and modify and/or create a packet and send it?

Details:

- I have Windows OS.
- I would prefer an easy to use and easy to understand program.
- If possible, a program that can create and modify packets would be
  nice. But if there is no program that can do both please point me to
  two programs that can do each.
- If there is one out there with a GUI, that would be very helpful to me.
- A program that intercepts packets and allows for modifying, not just
  HTTP.

I have tried [TcpCatcher](http://www.tcpcatcher.org/), but for some reason it does not seem to capture any packets.

Comment: Are you OK with installing a Linux-on-Windows software like Gygwin?

Comment: Check this list http://wiki.wireshark.org/Tools#Traffic_generators

Comment: @Nicolas Raoul  I have Cygwin installed on my computer.

Comment: @Cornelius  Thank you for this webpage, i was also wondering if there are any more that are not on that list?

Comment: I am also wondering if there is a program to intercept packets and allow for modifying them(Not just http)?

Comment: Re: why TcpCatcher doesn't capture packets:  were you capturing from the wireless card?  If so, windows won't capture anything without special software.   You must use a wired interface.

Answer (score 4):

I like to use [Network Protocol Analyzer](http://www.softperfect.com/products/networksniffer/) for this. It includes a network sniffer to capture network traffic, modify and resend it and has a function called "packet builder" that can create arbitrary packets from scratch and send them.

It's free, for Windows, with a GUI that I think it's reasonably easy to use (YMMV).

Answer (score 2):

My personal favourite in that realm is [Scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/).

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7738697/2015768), it seems to be possible to run on Windows platforms, too.

Comment: Scapy is wonderful, but there is no GUI as far as I know, and it is not very simple to learn. It is based off of Python, so if you have any experience in that language, you will have an advantage.